# Копирование всех стобцов VirtualTreeView при Drag and Drop

Tags: delphi, drag-n-drop, компоненты

Коллеги, при dragNdrop у меня копируется только первый столбец. Как скопировать все столбцы?

И вопрос, который может впоследствии возникнуть. Сейчас для примера я создал две записи и они одинаковые. Но в будущем я планирую первую запись `TItemNode1` расширить еще данными(как в примере поле `Quantity`, которое пока не используется), которые также должны быть скопированы. Как в этом случае поступить при копировании из одного дерева в другое?

[image: image here]

У меня стоит VirtualTreeView v6.6.

Вот код:

```
type
  PItemNode1 = ^TItemNode1;

  TItemNode1 = record
    Name: WideString;
    Order: string;
    Quantity:String;
  end;

type
  PItemNode2 = ^TItemNode2;

  TItemNode2 = record
    Name: WideString;
    Order: string;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  VT.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TItemNode1);
  VT2.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TItemNode2);
  VT.RootNodeCount := 2;
  VT2.RootNodeCount := 10;
end;
```

Процедура для вставки OLE данных

```
procedure TForm1.InsertData(Sender: TVirtualStringTree; DataObject: IDataObject;
  Formats: TFormatArray; Effect: Integer; Mode: TVTNodeAttachMode);
var
  FormatAccepted: Boolean; 
  i: Integer;
begin

  FormatAccepted := false;
  for i := 0 to High(Formats) do
  begin
    if Formats[i] = CF_VIRTUALTREE then
    begin
      if not FormatAccepted then
      begin
        Sender.ProcessDrop(DataObject, Sender.DropTargetNode, Effect, Mode);
        FormatAccepted := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Процедуры организации Drag and Drop

```
procedure TForm1.VT2DragAllowed(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
  Allowed := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.VT2DragDrop(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Source: TObject;
  DataObject: IDataObject; Formats: TFormatArray; Shift: TShiftState;
  Pt: TPoint; var Effect: Integer; Mode: TDropMode);
  procedure DetermineEffect;
  begin
    if Shift = [] then
    begin
      if Source = Sender then
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_MOVE
      else
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_COPY;
    end
    else
    begin
      if (Shift = [ssAlt]) or (Shift = [ssCtrl, ssAlt]) then
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_LINK
      else if Shift = [ssCtrl] then
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_COPY
      else
    end;
  end;

var
  Attachmode: TVTNodeAttachMode;
  Nodes: TNodeArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Nodes := nil;
  case Mode of
    dmAbove:
      Attachmode := amInsertBefore;
    dmOnNode:
      Attachmode := amAddChildLast;
    dmBelow:
      Attachmode := amInsertAfter;
  else
    Attachmode := amNowhere;
  end;
  if DataObject = nil then
  begin
  //VCL
    if Source is TVirtualStringTree then
    begin
      DetermineEffect;

      Nodes := VT2.GetSortedSelection(True);

      if Effect = DROPEFFECT_COPY then
      begin
        for i := 0 to High(Nodes) do
          VT2.CopyTo(Nodes[i], Sender.DropTargetNode, Attachmode, false);
      end
      else
        for i := 0 to High(Nodes) do
          VT2.MoveTo(Nodes[i], Sender.DropTargetNode, Attachmode, false);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    // OLE drag&drop.
    if Source is TBaseVirtualTree then
      DetermineEffect
    else
    begin
      if Boolean(Effect and DROPEFFECT_COPY) then
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_COPY
      else
        Effect := DROPEFFECT_MOVE;
    end;
    InsertData(Sender as TVirtualStringTree, DataObject, Formats, Effect,
      Attachmode);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.VT2DragOver(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Source: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; State: TDragState; Pt: TPoint; Mode: TDropMode;
  var Effect: Integer; var Accept: Boolean);
// Возвращает True, если AParent - дочерний узел ANode.
  function IsNodeParent(AParent, ANode: PVirtualNode): Boolean;
  var
    NextParent: PVirtualNode;
  begin
    NextParent := AParent;
    repeat
      NextParent := NextParent.Parent;
    until (NextParent = Sender.RootNode) or (NextParent = nil) or
      (NextParent = ANode);
    Result := ANode = NextParent;
  end;

var
  i: Integer;
  Nodes: TNodeArray;
begin
  Accept := True;
  if (Assigned(Sender.DropTargetNode)) and
    (Sender.DropTargetNode <> Sender.RootNode) then
    Nodes := (Sender as TVirtualStringTree).GetSortedSelection(True);
  if Length(Nodes) > 0 then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(Nodes) - 1 do
    begin
      Accept :=
        (not IsNodeParent(Sender.DropTargetNode, Nodes[i]))
        and (not(Sender.DropTargetNode = Nodes[i]));
      if not Accept then Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Инициализируем узлы ПРАВОГО дерева и заполняем их текстом

```
procedure TForm1.VT2GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  ItemNode: PItemNode2;

begin
  ItemNode := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(ItemNode) then
  begin
    case Column of
      0:
        CellText := ItemNode^.Name;
      1:
        CellText := ItemNode^.Order;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.VT2InitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
var
  ItemNode: PItemNode2;
begin
  ItemNode := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(ItemNode) then
    if Length(ItemNode^.Name) = 0 then
      ItemNode^.Name := 'Node Index № ' + IntToStr(Node.Index);
      ItemNode^.Order := IntToStr(Node.Index);
end;
```

Получим новый текст для узла после того как узел брошен

```
procedure TForm1.VT2NewText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; NewText: string);
var
  ItemNode: PItemNode2;
begin
  ItemNode := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(ItemNode) then
  begin
    case Column of
      0:
        ItemNode^.Name := NewText;
      1:
        ItemNode^.Order := NewText; // В дебагере до этой строки не доходим
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Инициализируем узлы ЛЕВОГО дерева и заполняем их текстом

```
procedure TForm1.VTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  ItemNode: PItemNode1;
begin
  ItemNode := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(ItemNode) then
    case Column of
      0:
        CellText := ItemNode^.Name;
      1:
          CellText := ItemNode^.Order;
    end;
end;
procedure TForm1.VTInitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; ParentNode,
  Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
var
  ItemNode: PItemNode1;
begin
  ItemNode := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(ItemNode) then
    if Length(ItemNode^.Name) = 0 then
      ItemNode^.Name := 'VT1_Node № ' + IntToStr(Node.Index);
      ItemNode^.Order := IntToStr(Node.Index);
end;
end.
```

Comment: NewText в контексте Drag&Drop вам не нужен. Для его реализации вам в обязательном порядке необходимо реализовать события OnLoadNode / OnSaveNode для приемника и источника соответственно. Если дойдут руки - оформлю ответом, пока вот так.

Comment: Спасибо, было бы здорово увидеть маленький пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения из первого столбца копируются, потому что в `vt.TreeOptions.StringOptions` выставлено `SaveCaptions` в True. В этом случае vt самостоятельно сохраняет содержимое главного столбца и при drop - вызывает `OnNewText`, который и устанавливает значение. Посему - при реализации полноценного сохранения и загрузки данных **крайне желательно** выставить `SaveCaptions` в False.

Чтобы реализовать полноценный Drag&Drop между разными VT, следует использовать события этого компонента OnLoadNode и OnSaveNode. Ввиду того, что предполагается расширение хранимых данных (и сами структуры данных у деревьев разные), следует использовать какой-нибудь широко распространенный формат хранения, например JSON, XML или ProtoBuf. В качестве примера я возьму реализацию XML из штатной поставки Delphi.

---

Итак, подготовительный этап. Эти методы нам понадобятся для сохранения и загрузки текстовых данных (xml) в поток (TStream) из событий OnSave/OnLoad:

```pascal
procedure StringToStream(const Astr: string; Stream: TStream);
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  i: integer;
begin
  Bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Astr);
  i := Length(Bytes);
  Stream.Write(i, SizeOf(integer));
  if i > 0 then
    Stream.WriteBuffer(Bytes[0], i);
end;

procedure StreamToString(var Astr: string; Stream: TStream);
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  i: integer;
begin
  Stream.Read(i, SizeOf(integer));
  SetLength(Bytes, i);
  if i > 0 then
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Bytes[0], i);

  Astr := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);
end;
```

Следующий этап - это загрузка/запись самих данных. Здесь код несколько абстрактный и без обработки возможного отсутствия данных, для сокращения объема.

```pascal
procedure RecordToXML(const Rec: TMyRecord1; RootNode: IXMLNode);
begin
  RootNode.AddChild('FullName').Text:=Rec.Name;
  // и так далее.
end;

procedure XMLToRecord(var Rec: TMyRecord2; RootNode: IXMLNode);
begin
  Rec.SomeName:=RootNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('FullName').Text;
  // и так далее.
end;
```

Собственно, осталось только реализовать сами OnSaveNode в передатчике и OnLoadNode в приемнике (остальное, необходимое для работы Drag&Drop у вас уже реализовано):

```pascal
procedure TmyForm.vt1SaveNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Stream: TStream);
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  Rec: pMyRecord1;
  s: string;
begin
  XML:=NewXMLDocument;
  Node:=XML.AddChild('root');
  // тут получаем нужный record из Sender-а, и потом:
  RecordToXML(Rec, Node); // записали в XML-контейнер

  XML.SaveToXML(s);
  StringToStream(s, Stream); // всё, наш контейнер с данными ушел блуждать
  // по внутренностям механизма Drag&Drop
end;

procedure TmyForm.vt2LoadNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Stream: TStream);
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  Rec: pMyRecord2;
  s: string;
begin
  StreamToString(s, Stream);// возможно - перед этим стоит сделать Stream.Position:=0;
  XML:=LoadXMLData(s);
  Node:=XML.DocumentElement;
  // получаем Rec и потом:
  XMLToRecord(Rec, Node);
end;
```

P.S. Судя по скриншоту из вопроса - используется RAD Studio 10. Однако, код в достаточной мере адаптирован для работы в предыдущих версиях среды.

P.P.S. нужно не забыть в uses подключить модули `XML.XMLIntf` и `XML.XMLDoc`.

P.P.P.S. Судя по всему, вы использовали код из статьи о VT, выложенной Quadro на винграде. На всякий случай (надеюсь, это не запрещено?) приведу здесь ссылку на статью (вложение внизу первого сообщения в теме): [Статья о Virtual Tree View](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-118457.html)

Comment: cпасибо большое за подробное объяснение. Но что-то не получается у меня. попробовал разобраться самостоятельно, почитал про XML, все равно не выходит. В методах `RecordToXML` и `XMLToRecord` маленькая опечатка они видимо должны принимать указатель на структуру. При переносе узла из одного дерева в другое ничего не происходит. Поюзал отладчик, выяснилось, что в методе `RecordToXML` вызывается исключение. Если в строке `RootNode.AddChild('FullName').Text:=Rec.Name;` заменить на `RootNode.AddChild('FullName').Text:='lalala'`, то все ок и узел уже появляется,но пустой

Comment: и исключение уже возникает в методе `XMLToRecord`. Что я делаю не так? Для наглядности выложил [полностью код](https://pastebin.com/Uz7BzMjM) Использую RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo. Есть еще у меня проблема в том, что я уже использую потоки для сохранения и загрузки дерева в файл(в коде по ссылке видно). Как это отразится на код, который Вы привели? Спасибо еще раз за помощь!

Comment: @Deluxe обратите внимание на комментарии в коде. в частности: `// тут получаем нужный record из Sender-а, и потом:`. **Cперва** получаем, а **потом** работаем с ним. Код получения я не стал приводить, он в вашем коде встречается неоднократно.

Comment: прощу прощения за невнимательность. Да действительно пытаюсь записать и считать пустые данные. 
Мне даже отладчик об этом подсказывал, не догадался. Теперь все работает спасибо большое!

Comment: Я только учусь программировать, можно я задам Вам еще пару вопросов?

Comment: **1.** По Вашему опыту для решения такой задачи лучше(экономней, быстрее) сделать две структуры как у меня или одну общую на два дерева? Это я спрашиваю на тот случай вдруг мне придется первую _структуру(источник)_ расширить данными, то тогда чтобы было куда копировать придется и вторую также расширить. Может лучше и экономнее держать одну общую большую структуру на два дерева?

Comment: Я полагаю, что в таком случае 
_дерево-приемник_ будет содержать в полном объеме все данные _дерева-источника_, которые в _приемник_ могут никогда и не попасть. Незачем же держать в _приемнике_  например,
весь каталог, а выгоднее скопировать только те, которые нужны пользователю  Как думаете?

Comment: **2.** В событти `OnLoadNode` _приемника_ я использую класс `TReader` для загрузки дерева из файла. 
И теперь каждый раз когда я кидаю узел, исполняется этот код, с потоками просходит ерунда и нчиего не работает.
Как правильно поступить в этом случае? Создать переменную-флаг, которая бы нам говорила что сейчас происходит
и выполнять нужный кусок кода? Или есть другие более грамотные решения?

Comment: @Deluxe на SO не приветствуется решение сопутствующих вопросов (не влияющих на интерпретацию основного) в комментариях, их могут потереть в любой момент. Задайте новые вопросы и получите ответы от специалистов, наиболее компетентных в данной области. Вкратце - п.1: зависит от задачи, п.2 - в комментариях не решить.

Comment: понял, спасибо!